# Placing shape inside a random polygon

Tags: integration, geometry, algorithms, area

I have an irregular shape that has many objects distributed upon its surface. How can I squeeze a shape in between these objects in such away that it stays within the irregular shape boundaries and away (as much as possible) from the other objects. Please refer to the below link for image (Sorry for the trouble, I can't put images directly just yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZpvS.png

Please let me know if you have any ideas on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the shape you want to place is regular (circle, square), you can try an approach of producing a [distance map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) and then taking local maxima of the map as good candidates where to place the center of your shape.

If your shape is a squeezed regular shape (ellipse, rectangle), you can scale you image anisotropically prior to generating distance map.

In case of irregular shape, I would suggest building a potential field (for example, with the same distance map) that gives huge penalty for points inside the objects and outside the boundary and fading penalty for all other points. After that, you need to solve optimization problem, where you can choose from a [variety of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Optimization_algorithms).